# iOS initializing any variable crashes the app

Tags: objective-c, ios

When I try to initialize any variable, my app crashes

```
NSString *str = @"Some String";
```

It crashes with the error message - "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
This stmt is inside a function. Everywhere else in the program the initialization is working but when i call this function, my app crashes giving the error message
Here is my function

```
+ (NSString *) recvToFile:(NSString *)_fileName {

@try {
    int _sz = [self recvNumber:4];
    uint8_t t[_sz];
    NSMutableData *data = nil;//[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSMutableData *fileData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSString *str = @"Some String";
        long _pos = 0;
        NSString *_fullPath = _fileName;
        while (_sz > _pos) {
            long _c = [m_sin read:t maxLength:_sz];
            _pos += _c;
            data = [NSData dataWithBytes:t length:_c];
            if([Misc checkTempFileExists:_fileName]==nil)
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:_fullPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
            [fileData appendData:data];
        }
    [fileData writeToFile:_fullPath atomically:YES];
    NSDictionary *attr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:_fullPath error:nil];

    long long length = [[attr valueForKey:@"NSFileSize"] intValue];
    if (length >= _sz)
        return (_fullPath);
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
}
return (nil);
}
```

Everywhere else initializing is working but not for this function

Comment: You will need to post more code, we can not say anything that will help you with just this line of code.

Comment: Or a backtrace would be useful. It's possible that you are trying to access this variable from outside it's scope.

Comment: Doesn't look like `str` is used in that code other than the initialisation. Either there's something you're not showing us, or that line is a red herring. Could you show us the back trace?

Comment: I have edited my question to have that function which is giving error
Actually I m getting error at fileData Initialization and if i comment out that line then getting error at next initialization i.e. NSString *str = @"Some String";

Comment: @Jasarien that str i just used for testing purpose to check whether it gives error only in NSData initialization or for every initialization

Comment: what do u mean by backtrace and how to do that?

Comment: The call stack shown in the debug navigator in Xcode when a crash occurrs. You can also type `bt` in the debugger to see it when the program is paused.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using class method and in that method you are initializing nonstatic string, i think tats the problem.Instead of that Can you please check it with static NSString=@"Some String"; after the import files in .m file.The same way you can create fullpath string also.Then u can assign like fullpath=_fileName;@aswinikumar..sorry for my english

Comment: but i m calling this function for huge no of times, it works for some function call while not for other